# Giving a JSON to an ApiService in angular2

Tags: json, angular

I'm currently doing a basic app where you enter data about someone, and it inserts it into a database. I choose a number, a color, a name, and a phone number. I have an API SERVICE to insert this data on a database, but I have a parsing error, without using the Parse function ! Here is my code :

```
export class HomePage {

  ticket: any = {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public apiService: ApiService) {
    this.ticket = {
      number: null,
      name: '',
      phone: '',
      color: ''
    };
  }

  insert(){
    console.log(this.ticket);
    this.apiService.call('insert', 'tombola', this.ticket)
        .then( response => {})
        .catch( error => {})
  }
}
```

Here is my ApiService :

```
export class ApiService {
  public API_URL;
  public BASE_URL;
  data;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.API_URL = "myapilink";
    this.data = {};
  }

  call(action, entity, params){

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      var link = this.API_URL;
      var data = JSON.stringify({action: action, entity: entity, params: params});
      console.log(data);

      this.http.post(link, data)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            resolve(this.data);
          }, error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
    });
  }
}
```

With my HTML page :

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Numéro</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="ticket.number" type="number" value=""></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Couleur</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="ticket.color" interface="popover">
      <ion-option value="bleu">Bleu</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="vert">Vert</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="violet">Violet</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Nom</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="ticket.name" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Téléphone</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="ticket.phone" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <br><br><br>

  <button ion-button block color="secondary" (click)="insert()">Insérer</button>
```

Everytime I try to insert a record, I've got the same error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Where does that W come from ? Sometimes it's a d at position 0.

Can't find out why it's not working... Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: The response of your http call is probably not returning a valid JSON

Comment: Not sure it's coming from the HTTP return. For now the api simply returns a word

Comment: If it's just returning a word, why are you trying to convert it to a json `map(res => res.json())`?

Comment: Definitly looks like a bad response from your server. Try doing `.do(res => console.log(res)`) before you do `.map(res => res.json())` to look at the data returned

Comment: Also, avoid using `var` for variables, use `let` or `const` instead. Your code  is a bit confusing, since you have three different variables at different scopes called `data`. Using `var` makes it even harder to know where things are scoped..